# disable Tab post on nav-menus page (Admin)

Tags: posts, functions, customization, menus, pages

Looking for to hide post on nav-menus page like in the picture.

I tried admin Adminimize but it's does not work. so I'm looking for a custom code to add on functions.php
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind, there are two different ways to manage Menus in WordPress. One is through Appearance > Menus, which is the screen you're showing. The other is the Customizer.

**Appearance > Menus : no coding required**

You can prevent Posts from showing on a per-user basis. Just go to the top right corner of your screen, choose Screen Options, un-check Posts, and choose Screen Options again to close the panel.

**Customizer**

I'm not aware of a way to hide any registered post types specifically from the Customizer view. Hopefully someone with more Customizer know-how will reply if there is indeed a way.

Fortunately, this last section will remove Posts from both the Menus screen and the Customizer.

**Changing a registered post type**

When a post type is registered, there are arguments you can pass so that that post type will not appear in nav menus. Specifically, `show_in_nav_menus`.

Since Post is a built-in post type, you can't adjust where it's initially created. You'll need to use `register_post_type_args` to allow you to adjust the already-registered post type.

```
<?php
add_filter('register_post_type_args', 'wpse_remove_posts_from_nav_menus', 20, 2);
function wpse_remove_posts_from_nav_menus($args, $post_type) {
    if($post_type == 'post') {
        $args['show_in_nav_menus'] => false;
    }
    return $args;
}
?>
```

This should prevent Posts from appearing in either the menu management screen or the Customizer.

Comment: Thanks. I  added your custom code. but it's break the page

Comment: It was missing a semicolon. Updated above.

Comment: Yes after (false) . But i still have the same breaking page.

Comment: It's work! just replace => false with = false .  thanks again

Comment: Code updated to working version - if this worked, perhaps you could mark as the answer.